# Kafka Stream Process API batch commit (based number of messages)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Kafka Processor API and I don't want only to use a time based approach to decide when to commit the processed messages, within the task, but I would do that based either on a number of processed messages or on timeout.
Is there any way to implement that in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processor API allows you to "request" commits via `ProcessorContext#commit()`. Calling this method, Kafka Streams will commit as soon as possible. This should allow you to implement some `Processor` internal counter and call commit() base in this counter.

Additionally, you can either use there configures commit interval, or disable it effectively be setting it to `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

You can also schedule punctuation and call commit() from there either based on event-time or wall-clock time to get the "timeout" behavior you want.

Comment: I've tried the ProcessorAPI calling the <pre> ProcessorContext#commit() <code> at each read or based on an internal counter and in both cases I've noticed it's very slow compared to StreamDSL. I've a Kafka to Kafka with source and sink topics. With StreamDSL a commit on the sink topic is reflected back on source topic and the performance are better than ProcessorAPI. I've tried with 10 messages and with StreamDSL the time to process  messages by a consumer from sink topic is in the range of a few ms while with ProcessorAPI it takes a few seconds. How can I improve with ProcessorAPI?

Comment: Not sure. DSL only a wrapper on top of Processor API, and thus, it's unclear to me why it might be slower...